# Trying to create ol of urls

Tags: html-lists, href

Trying to use href with anchor tags. However, even using the instructor's code to create a preview and trying to open her sites on the preview, it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:3002/. When you click on the links on this page it goes to the desired site.
[Instructors code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEOUt.png)
[What the preview looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PteZd.png)
[Page that opens when I click on any link in the preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAHtv.png)

I can then click on the links and go to the desired sites.

I'm a total noob. Played around for a couple of hours, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry, am new to the site. Will not upload images in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are asking why does the link (http://127.0.0.1:3002/) takes you to that webpage. It is because html is used to describe how a website looks. Every html code you write creates a link to website as you can see in the preview on this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PteZd.png). And this website will open in a browser as you can see.

Hope this helps.